# Tensor Algebra Problem

Tags: tensors, feyncalc

I am just getting started with tensor algebra using Mathematica. I could use some help with a simple problem I am starting with at my website:

http://www.tifis.org/mathematicaproblem.pdf

An acquaintance of mine showed me how to solve this problem using the "FeynCalc" add-on to Mathematica, and his solution is also at my website:

http://www.tifis.org/feyncalcsolution.pdf

How can I solve this problem using Mathematica without any add-on like FeynCalc, just using Mathematica's built-in tensor software?

The problem I'm having with FeynCalc is that it seems to require me to be online to some extent, even after downloading the software, whereas I would like to just work offline. Please feel free to contact me by email too, andrewthyman@gmail.com. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to introduce tensors so you can perform computations without add-ons?

Comment: Hi disp0sable-h3r0, I am hoping that someone can write up some Mathematica code to solve the problem WITHOUT FeynCalc, just like my acquaintance did WITH FeynCalc.  The problem is very simple and brief, and if I can see how it’s solved without FeynCalc, then that will help me toward solving much more complicated problems offline.

Comment: I am quite busy now to attempt the full solution. I will try when I find some time. I did write how to correctly introduce tensors without a package. Then you can think of sums and multiplications. If you cannot come up with the answer, I will try to get back as I said but I am pretty swamped

Comment: Thanks, if you can do it that would be fantastic.  It’s beyond my novice abilities.  I’m happy to reciprocate somehow.  Please feel free to use the email address I gave.  Cheers,  Andrew

Comment: There is some tensor documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SymbolicTensors.html) that might be of use.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, I will check it out.  Incidentally, I am having better luck with Feyncalc now, so that may suffice.  I “downloaded” Feyncalc, and then “installed” Feyncalc, but I did not realize that each time the computer is restarted one must also “load” Feyncalc by evaluating “<<FeynCalc`” which I have now done.  So it’s working good for me so far. 

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the answer to my question in the comment is yes, the following is the flat space metric that you have in four spacetime dimensions.

```
metric = { {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
```

The simple command

```
metric // MatrixForm
```

will show it in matrix notation. Note, however, that if you include the `MatrixForm` you will not be able to perform computations.

In general, tensors are lists of lists and you can perform all the usual manipulations amongst them.

If this does not help -or you want a more explicit example- please let me know.